# Put a parent div around entire webpage

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to put a black frame around my entire web page.

I would like the parent div to be around the entire page, not just the bottom. My HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
<!-- Header --> 
        <section id = "top" class = "top">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class = text-center>Sarah Hynds</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!------ tabs ------>
        <nav class="mynav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Interests</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <hr id="separator" width="35%" color="black">
        <div class="floating-box" id="about"></div>
        <div class=floating-box" id="profile">
        </div>
        <div class="parentDiv"></div>
</body>
```

My css looks like this:

```
.parentDiv { 
width: 90%; 
border: 1px solid #000000; 
margin-top: 5%; 
margin-left: 5%; 
margin-right: 5%; 
height: 100%; 
display: inline-block; 
padding-bottom: 50px;
display: inline-block;
white-space: nowrap; }
```

How can I put the border around the entire page?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Couldn't you just put the border on the `<body>` tag?

Comment: Something like this: `body {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
`

Comment: That div has no closing tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>
<div class="parentDiv">
<!-- Header --> 
        <section id = "top" class = "top">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class = text-center>Sarah Hynds</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!------ tabs ------>
        <nav class="mynav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Interests</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <hr id="separator" width="35%" color="black">
        <div class="floating-box" id="about"></div>
        <div class=floating-box" id="profile">
        </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Simply just wrap it around of the content you want it to affect. :-)

Comment: Thank you, fixed the problem!